# Converting Points to Line using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, route

I have a shapefile that contains points (xy coordinates) that display several different routes for a transit agency.  In the attribute field I'm given information on what route each point corresponds to and also the sequential numbering for each point in each route (starting back at 1 for every new route).

How do I convert these points into lines separated by each of the routes?

I used the point to line tool but it created extra lines connecting each of the routes together.  I even tried specifying the Line Field and Sort Field to the fields with the route numbers/sequential numbering and got an error.

Comment: You could try creating a new field concatenating your routes and sequential numbers and use that as the line field.

Comment: You mean have the route number and the sequence number in the same field?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Paul!  I'm just curious how to do that, have a new sequential number for each new route? (route 14=1, route 24=2, etc.?)

Comment: You could do that, or any other way that would keep it unique. It doesn't have to be sequential. If the route numbers are unique, just use that.

Comment: Is it possible a point shares in more than one routes?for example 2 different routes intersect in one point?if not,you already have unique points by combining two fields:[line field]=Route number and [sort field]=point number in each route.So Points to Line tool can create distinct lines based on Route numbers.

Comment: Would you be able to edit more details of your input data into your question, please?  A diagram with some test rows of the point attribute table and the lines that should result would probably suffice to make your question easier to answer.  Also, you mention an error but do not include precisely what that and the syntax used to trigger it were.